# Exponential homeomorphism from $(-1/2,1/2)$ to $S^1\setminus \{-1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the circle $S^1$ as the set of complex numbers $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| = 1$. I want to prove that the continuous map $p\colon\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ given by $p(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ induces a homeomorphism $p{\restriction}_{(-1/2,1/2)}\colon (-1/2,1/2)\to S^1\setminus\{-1\}$. Do we need complex logarithms for that or is there any other way?

Comment: You do need an inverse, and that would be precisely the logarithm (restricted ofc).

Comment: @NelliKuukeri Aren't complex logarithms multi-valued?

Comment: That's why you restrict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $e^{2\pi i x_n} \to e^{2\pi ix}$ with $x \in (-\frac  1 2, \frac  12)$. Then some subsequence of $x_n$ tends to some point $y$ in the closed interval $[-\frac  1 2, \frac  12]$. But then $e^{2\pi i y} = e^{2\pi ix}$ so $x,y$ differ by an  integer. You can easily convince yourself this is possinel only when $x=y$.

Now, every subsequence of $x_n)$ has a further subseqeunce converging to $x$ which implies $x_n \to x$.

Comment: Are you proving injectivity?

Comment: No, I am proving continuity of the inverse. But a proof of injectivity is actually  hidden in may argument , so I will injectivity to  you. @Jxt921